# How would you construct this SQL query? (MySQL)

Tags: sql, mysql

Let assume we have these tables:

### product

```
product_id
product_name
```

### category

```
category_id
category_name
```

### product_in_category

```
product_in_category_id
product_id
category_id
```

how would you get all products that are not in specific category in the product_in_category table (without duplicates).

In other words, all products that are not been assigned to category 10, for instance.
Also, if one product is in categories 1, 5 and 10, it shouldn't come up the result.

Comment: When you mention "categories 1, 5, and 10"--do you mean *all* of them, or at least one of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using LEFT JOIN/IS NULL:

```
   SELECT p.*
     FROM PRODUCT p
LEFT JOIN PRODUCT_IN_CATEGORY pic ON pic.product_id = p.product_id
                                 AND pic.category_id = 10
    WHERE pic.product_in_category_id IS NULL
```

### Using NOT IN

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM PRODUCT p
 WHERE p.product_id NOT IN (SELECT pic.product_id
                              FROM PRODUCT_IN_CATEGORY pic
                             WHERE pic.category_id = 10)
```

### Using NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM PRODUCT p
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                     FROM PRODUCT_IN_CATEGORY pic
                    WHERE pic.product_id = p.product_id
                      AND pic.category_id = 10)
```

### Which is best?

It depends on if the columns being compared are nullable (values can be NULL) or not.  If they are [nullable, then NOT IN/NOT EXISTS are more efficient](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/).  If the columns are [***not*** nullable, then LEFT JOIN/IS NULL is more efficient (MySQL only)](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM product_in_category WHERE category_id!=10
```

or am I missing something? I guess I was missing the no duplicates part, look at InSane's better answer.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after I wrote it and InSane already presented a better solution, in any case.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT product_id FROM product
LEFT OUTER JOIN product_in_category
ON product.product_id = product_in_category.product_id
WHERE product_in_category.product_id IS NULL
GROUP BY product_id
```